# Fila - Python (ordem)

Tags: python, fila

Vamos simular uma situação de fila no terminal de ônibus.
Escreva uma função que recebe uma LISTA DE NOMES (strings) que indica a ordem de
chegada das pessoas para pegar um ônibus no terminal.

Sua função deverá criar uma fila e inserir as pessoas nela, por ordem de chegada
(ordem em que aparecem na lista recebida como parâmetro).

Cuidado: existe um passageiro, chamado Samuel, que causou problemas no terminal
ontem. Hoje, o fiscal irá impedi-lo de embarcar, para que ele preste
esclarecimentos.

OU SEJA: você vai adicionar os nomes na fila, mas deverá ignorar o
Samuel, que não é autorizado a embarcar.

Depois, removendo um por um da fila, crie uma nova lista que mostra a ordem
em que as pessoas entrarão no ônibus.

Sua função irá, ao final, retornar a lista de embarque.

Exemplos:
embarca(['Jose', 'Henrique', 'Carla'])
--> retorna a lista [ 'Jose', 'Henrique', 'Carla' ], indicando a ordem de
embarque.

embarca(['Jose', 'Samuel', 'Carla'])
--> retorna a lista ['Jose', 'Carla']

```
class Fila:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fila = deque() # atributo fila é um objeto do tipo deque

    def insere(self, novo):
        self.fila.append(novo) # uso append para inserir no final

    def remove(self):
        return self.fila.popleft() # popleft remove da esquerda (início)

    def tamanho(self):
        return len(self.fila) # usa len para calcular tamanho da fila

    def vazia(self):
        if len(self.fila) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

fila = Fila()
def embarca(pessoas):
    lista = []
    for i in range(len(pessoas)):
        if i != "Samuel":
            fila.insere(i)
        c = fila.remove()
        lista.append(c)
    return lista
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o Python já possui a estrutura `collections.deque` que te permite gerenciar uma fila, você não precisa criar uma classe para isso. Basta utilizá-la diretamente na sua função:

```py
from typing import List, Text
from collections import deque

def embarca(nomes: List[Text]) -> List[Text]:
    fila = deque()
    for nome in nomes:
        if nome != 'Samuel':
            fila.append(nome)
    return list(fila)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LightblueOrneryHashmap)</sup>

Na função é inicialmente criada uma fila vazia, percorre-se os nomes da lista de pessoas que foi recebido como parâmetro e quando não for Samuel é adicionado o nome na fila; finalmente é retornado uma lista com o conteúdo da fila.

> **Nota:** A solução remove da fila todas as pessoas chamadas Samuel, o que no mundo real seria bem inconveniente com os *Samuéis*, dado que todos pagariam por aquilo que apenas um fez. Como não fica explícito no enunciado um meio de diferenciá-los, fica aqui minhas desculpas a todos os outros *Samuéis*.

O resultado pode ser verificado com:

```py
assert embarca(['Jose', 'Henrique', 'Carla']) == [ 'Jose', 'Henrique', 'Carla' ]
assert embarca(['Jose', 'Samuel', 'Carla']) == ['Jose', 'Carla']
```

Entendo que por ser um exercício que pede explicitamente o uso de filas essa seja a solução esperada, mas o mesmo problema poderia ser resolvido de outras formas de maneira mais simples. Utilizando compreensão de listas, por exemplo, é possível resolver com uma linha de código trivial:

```
def embarca(nomes: List[Text]) -> List[Text]:
    return [nome for nome in nomes if nome != 'Samuel']
```